# How to modify URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have the following course category and courses.

```
                          JAVA //Course Category
              Course1       Course2      Course3      Course4


                    Cloud Computing //Course Category
              Course1       Course2      Course3      Course4
```

If I hit any course for eg course 1 of JAVA I get url like this..

```
wwww.fugence.com/course-cube/course-category.php?course-name="Course1"
```

I want URL like this..

```
wwww.fugence.com/course-cube/JAVA/Course1

JAVA -> Course category
Course1 -> Course of category JAVA
```

All Course category and courses are coming dynamically from database. Back end I used code igniter front end for displaying course I used core PHP. I dont want extensions like .php? in my URL. How to do this in my case.?

Comment: What have you got for your code so far?  If it's coming from the database it should be straight forward, and within code igniter you'd just need to configure the routes and function calls to accept the data

Comment: Yes. I can do that. But I have time constraints thats why am looking for short cut... Like url rewirting...

Comment: your application in codeigniter? then place your controller code and view code in your question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change $config['enable_query_strings] (line 185) in the config/config.php file to FALSE.

Second, I'm ASSUMING that course-category.php is the controller. If you want to take that out, you're going to have to do some mod_rewrite work in the htaccess. I don't do htaccess stuff, so I can't help you there.

Otherwise, the following is as close as you're going to be able to get:

wwww.fugence.com/course-cube/course-category/JAVA/Course1

That's really just:

```
base_url() . 'course-category/'.$main_cat.'/'.$sub_cat
```

Comment: Looking back at your comments, this doesn't answer your question. You want mod_rewrite and I can't give that to you. CI itself provides an example htaccess for removing the base index file from the URL, but that's as far as it goes and that's as far as I'm going to go. If you need more than that, it extends beyond CI and beyond PHP itself into the server config. I'm sure there are better places to ask for that.